# To compare the content of two folders by some app in OS X

Tags: macos, latex, comparison, meld

I am improving my friend's LaTeX document at folder 1/2, while he is editing the folder 1/1.

The initial contents of the folders is the same.

**How can you meld the two folders to one such that all files are melded?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're wanting to find the differences in files in two folders and merge the changes?

If you're looking for a GUI utility you can use FileMerge which can be found at `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/` if you have Apple's Developer Tools installed. It has some odd bugs - mostly to deal with handling file encoding.

If you're looking for something faster and nicer check out [Changes.app](http://connectedflow.com/changes/) - it's not cheap but has been worth the price of admission several times over for me.

If you want to do it via the command line you can use `diff` to find the differences and then manually merge the files together as it will list all the differences. (eg. `diff ~/Desktop/a ~/Desktop/b`)

Answer (score 2):

Since the mac is running a version of unix, you can use all of the tried, tested and true commands from the established UNIX heritage.

[UNIX Shell Comparison of Directories Tutorial](http://www.unixtutorial.org/2008/06/how-to-compare-directories-in-unix/)

Answer (score 2):

The following code is made by [Git-community](https://gist.github.com/raw/88581/09d4c86e9abfd68102b51f1e38002fc917cbe84d/git-opendiff)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Filemerge.app must not already be open before running
# this script, or opendiff below will return immediately,
# and the TMPDIRs deleted before it gets the chance to read
# them.

[ \$# -eq 7 ] &amp;&amp; opendiff "\$2" "\$5"
EOF
chmod +x merge.sh
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=./merge.sh git-diff 


if test $# = 0; then
   OLD=`git-write-tree`
elif test "$1" = --cached; then
   OLD=HEAD
   NEW=`git-write-tree`
   shift
fi
if test $# -gt 0; then
   OLD="$1"; shift
fi
test $# -gt 0 &amp;&amp; test -z "$CACHED" &amp;&amp; NEW="$1"

TMPDIR1=`mktemp -d`
git-archive --format=tar $OLD | (cd $TMPDIR1; tar xf -)
if test -z "$NEW"; then
   TMPDIR2=$(git rev-parse --show-cdup)
   test -z "$cdup" &amp;&amp; TMPDIR2=.
else
   TMPDIR2=`mktemp -d`
   git-archive --format=tar $NEW | (cd $TMPDIR2; tar xf -)
fi

opendiff $TMPDIR1 $TMPDIR2 | cat
rm -rf $TMPDIR1
test ! -z "$NEW" &amp;&amp; rm -rf $TMPDIR2
```

You can then run

```
opendiff folder1 folder2
```

to achieve what I want.